Controlling stacked objects using Geometry Nodes
I'm quite new to geometry nodes, so I'm struggling with stacking objects.
Simply speaking, I want to achieve this effect:

That is, to distribute objects in a grid, randomise how much objects are present in a grid, distribute the whole system on a plane and, if on the first layer there isn't any object, the subsequent layers don't spawn any object above the first one.
I only managed to distribute them along the grid and cube, but in this way I can't achieve randomness.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

So basically, the rule is simply to have an integer height for each point of the XY plane, and generate cubes above it accordingly ?

You could solve this task as follows:

Here I simply instantiate a few curves on a grid, which are then subdivided.
The individual curves are then given a random value, which I save in the Spline domain.
I can then use this value to compare the index of the points of each individual curve and thus create a selection for instantiating the cubes.
By playing around with the length and subdivision of the curves, as well as the Min and Max values in the Random Value node, you can influence the way in which the instantiation takes place.
(Blender 4.2.2+)

Or you could trim the curves randomly and select without the last point.

You are truly a life saver! That’s exactly what I’m looking for.

(Using Blender 4.2.3)
Approach
Starting from a grid, a random integer is drawn per grid point. This number is coding how many objects can be stacked above a grid point. Then the grid is duplicated in Z direction. Eventually, objects are spawned if the random value is less than the copy index.
GeometryNodes modifier

Dark pink nodes:  Grid creation and random stack height captured as an attribute labelled "Level Max".
Dark green nodes: Duplication of the grid in Z direction and capture of the copy index as an attribute labelled "Level". Grid instances must be realized to have different layouts.
Dark blue nodes: Instantiation at grid points with "Level" less than the randomized "Level Max".
Resources
(Blender 4.2.3+)
